# Create an Akka actor remotely without a new ActorSystem

Tags: scala, jvm, akka, actor, remote-actors

I've been over the documentation several times now (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/remoting.html) and through the example here (https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-remote) and through others, and I still can't figure out how to do what I want to do. The closest answer I've found is this:  [how to start remote actors in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340514/how-to-start-remote-actors-in-scala), but it seems much more inconvenient than I'd think it would be.

I have a cluster of 12 machines to work on.  I would like to something along the lines of:

```
val system = ActorSystem("DistributedSystem", ConfigFactor.load.getConfig("distsys"))
val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(...)), "master")
```

and then inside of the master, something along the lines of:

```
override def preStart() = {
    for (i <- 0 until 11) {
        // I want each of these actors to be created remotely on 
        // a different machine
        context.actorOf(Props(new RemoteChild(...)), s"child$i")
    }
}
```

It seems like this would be a reasonably common use case. Is there something I'm missing, or is there a good way to do this (in terms of what my configuration should look like, or how many ActorSystems I really need)? I'm just struggling to synthesize a good solution right now.

Comment: If you don't want to start up JVMs on the target nodes then how do you expect this to work?  There has to be an Akka system up and running on a node where you want to target a remote deployment and that remote system also has to have remoting configured so its listening for requests such as this. All you have to do is that, and the rest can just be config that says that when you start a particular actor that its being targeted to a particular remote node. Pretty simple given what's actually going on under the hood. Are you expecting Akka to magically start up JVMs on remote nodes for you?

Comment: I removed that part of the question. I don't know what I was expecting.  Do I just need to have a separate part of the configuration for each machine I might want to spawn an ActorSystem on?  Or since they're all doing the same thing, and my ip addresses follow the format 192.168.1.{n} where n is from 1 to 12, can it dynamically figure out what the host is that it's running on, so that in my local program I can access the remote actors by just using the rule that the nth remote actor is on host 192.168.1.{n}?  Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2):

I think what it sounds like you want to do is deploy a set of actors to a set of remote nodes and then sit them behind a local router and pass messages to the router and let it farm the work out to the remote nodes.  To do that, you could try something like this:

```
val addresses = for(i <- 1 until 12) 
  yield AddressFromURIString(s"akka://RemoteSys@192.168.1.$i:2553")

val routerRemote = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteChild].withRouter(
  RemoteRouterConfig(RoundRobinRouter(12), addresses)))
```

This assumes that you have Akka running on those nodes with an `ActorSystem` called `RemoteSys` and it's using remoting configured for port 2553.  When you send a message to that `routerRemote` ref, it will now round-robin route the messages across your 12 worker nodes.