# AKKA: Confusion about programmatic remote deployment

Tags: scala, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am using [akka remote deployment](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.2/scala/remoting.html#programmatic-remote-deployment). I used logging to ensure if the actor has successfully deployed remotely. Here is my log info

```
[adaptiveCEP-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] [akka.tcp://adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2555/remote/akka.tcp/adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2554/user/disjunction/simple-2555-0.4631423946172286] hi, I am simple-2555-0.4631423946172286
[adaptiveCEP-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] [akka.tcp://adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2555/remote/akka.tcp/adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2554/user/disjunction/simple-2555-0.4631423946172286] hi, I am Actor[akka://adaptiveCEP/remote/akka.tcp/adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2554/user/disjunction/simple-2555-0.4631423946172286#1386676347]
```

It appears as if actor `simple-2555-0.4631423946172286#1386676347` is child actor of `disjunction` actor and both hosted on the same machine (no remote deployment of child). And the actor who is doing supervision is actor `akka.tcp://adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2555`.

According to [Top-Level Scopes for Actor Paths](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.2/scala/general/addressing.html#top-level-scopes-for-actor-paths):

> "/remote" is an artificial path below which all actors reside whose supervisors are remote actor references

Have I misunderstood something?

**If required**

```
val randomRouter = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Master],
      "disjunction")
```

Master.scala

```
val temp = context.actorOf(Props[SimpleClusterListener].withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(address))), "simple-" + port + "-" + Math.random())
temp ! "hi"
```

**Reference**

[Create an Akka actor remotely without a new ActorSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182975/create-an-akka-actor-remotely-without-a-new-actorsystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your actor is not deployed locally, it's on the remote machine

```
akka.tcp://adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2555/remote/akka.tcp/adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2554/user/disjunction/simple-2555-0.4631423946172286] hi, I am simple-2555-0.4631423946172286
```

This log item shows that your actor is running on actor system "adaptiveCEP" on "127.0.0.1:2555" machine and is being supervised by "disjunction" actor in "adaptiveCEP@127.0.0.1:2554"